# In clojure, is (= 'a 'a) referring to the 'same atom'?

Tags: java, clojure, lisp, scheme

In some implementations of Common LISP we can say that for the following expression

```
(eq 'a 'a)
```

Is `true` because `'a` and `'a` are the "same atom".

This may be implementation dependent, but it seems the phrase (used in a popular LISP teaching book) assumes that atoms of the same value are stored in the same location in memory.

In Java, two interned strings of the same value are stored in the same location in memory.

Now Clojure on the JVM inherits Java's legacy, but is it true to say that two atoms in Clojure (on JVM) having the same value are the same atom? (ie how does Clojure's atom storage mechanism work?)

Comment: Dialects of Common Lisp? What are these? What dialects? The usual Common Lisp implementations all implement ANSI Common Lisp. There are dialects of CL, but that is not of importance, since most people (incl. Lisp users) probably have never heard of them. But there are many dialects of Lisp. - Any Common Lisp will return T for (eq 'a 'a). a is also not an atom, but a symbol. The term 'atom' does also make no sense in this context. Historically everything that is not a cons cell is an atom.

Comment: "In Java, two strings of the same value are stored in the same location in memory." -- only if they are both interned.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, "atom" has a different meaning in Clojure than in most other Lisps. See http://clojure.org/atoms

Clojure's `=` function uses *value*-based equality. So two objects with equal values will be `=` even if they are stored in different locations in memory.

To test if two objects are actually the same object, at the same address in memory, use the `identical?` function.

Answer (score 6):

I think 'a and 'a are going to be different Java objects under the hood.  I believe this confirms that suspicion:

```
user> (def foo 5)
#'user/foo
user> (System/identityHashCode 'foo)
578999228
user> (System/identityHashCode 'foo)
1724482638
```

If you look at the actual implementation of [Symbol](http://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/1.2.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Symbol.java) in Clojure, you'll see that a symbol consists of a namespace and a name and those Strings MUST be interned strings.  The Symbol.equals() method relies on doing identity checks on those two strings, relying on string intern.

Answer (score 4):

I'll explain the Common Lisp part:

In Common Lisp (eq 'a 'a) returns always T.

Reason: at read time, the reader looks up *a*, and for both *a* it will look up the same symbol *a*. Since any symbol is EQ to itself, the expression returns always T.

This is true for most types of objects, but with a few exceptions. Numbers and characters, for example, are not necessary EQ in Common Lisp. The reason for that is efficiency. To compare these if they are the same number or same character one can use the function EQL.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Alex's and Stuart's answers, Symbols in Clojure could not be made to be `identical?` whenever they are `=` mostly because they may carry metadata. Two Symbols which have the same `.name` and `.namespace` components but different metadata will be `=` but not `identical?`.

Things could conceivably be arranged so that two Symbols with the same metadata, namespace and name would always be `identical?`, but that is (1) two much hassle for no real gain (since you'd still have some Symbols `=` but not `identical?`), (2) contrary to the idea that types which may carry metadata should normally be compared for value equality (to which metadata does not contribute), whereas actual pointer equality should be reserved for special situations (mostly involving interop).

Note that Clojure Keywords are a separate type for which `=` is indeed equivalent to `identical?`. (So clearly they cannot have metadata attached.)